# Python SocketServer deadlock issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, deadlock, socketserver

When I'm threading the SocketServer instance (the `serve_forever` method) I can quit it easily when sending the text "shutdown", which is what I expect.  However, if its not threaded then I run into the issue of it locking up and I can't figure out how to get around this.

The basic flow of the server itself is start->listen->get data->get the command from it->run the command (which is a plugin)->return the results.  Here's the code I use:

```py
import SocketServer as SS

NULL_RESP = {"status" : False, "data" : "No data received."}

class ASWCP_Daemon(SS.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()

        if self.data == "":
           self.request.sendall(json.dumps(NULL_RESP))
           return None

       tmp = self.data.split(" ", 1)

       cmd = tmp[0]
       args = ""

       try:
           args = str(tmp[1]).split(conf.command_parse)
    except:
           pass

       plugin = plugins["cmd"][cmd]['ref'].init(conf=conf, socket=self)

       try:
           if args[0] == "help":
            self.request.sendall(plugin.help)
       except IndexError:
           status,data = plugin.run(args)
           resp = {"status" : status, "data" : data}
           self.request.sendall(json.dumps(resp))

  if __name__ == "__main__":
   # Log is created here; conf = config file (irrelevant to this issue)

   try:
       if conf.tcp:
           if conf.threaded:
               import threading
               class ThreadedTCPServer(SS.ThreadingMixIn, SS.TCPServer):
                   pass

               server = ThreadedTCPServer((conf.host, conf.listen_port), ASWCP_Daemon)
           else:
               server = SS.TCPServer((conf.host, conf.listen_port), ASWCP_Daemon)
       else:
           server = SS.UDPServer((conf.host, conf.listen_port), ASWCP_Daemon)

       if conf.threaded:
           sthread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
           #sthread.daemon = True
           sthread.start()
       else:
           server.serve_forever()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       pass
```

The shutdown plugin's run method is this:

```py
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.socket == None:
            print "> No socket available"
            return (False,"")
        else:
            self.socket.log.info("Shutting down daemon")
            self.socket.server.shutdown()

            return (True,"")
```

If threaded this is fine, if its not then it gets as far as the `self.socket.server.shutdown()` method in the plugin.  `self.socket` is the instance of ASWCP_Daemon class.

Comment: Can you post the *full* problematic code? This code is not correctly indented (simply paste it from the editor, highlight it, and press `Ctrl+K` here), and `conf` is not defined, and it's missing the actual shutdown, and it contains irrelevant code (anything related to threading, since the problem occurs when threading is disabled).

Comment: Sorry been really busy so haven't had a chance to respond.  I fixed it and made it the answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

```py
    # Do shutdown() if threaded, else execute server_close()
    if self.sysconf.threaded:
        self.socket.server.shutdown()
    else:
        self.socket.server.server_close()

    return (True,"")
```

`self.sysconf` is the configuration for the daemon (`conf` in the code in the question), and `self.socket` is a reference to the stream handler.